# Inline lambda in a linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I need help creating an inline/multiline lambda within a LINQ expression.

```
List<myObject> someList = domainModel.someMethod();

Array result = (from r in someList
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = r.Text,
                    Value = r.Value.Select(r2=> { /* <<< Not sure how to "call it" */
                        string outputValue = "";

                        /* ** How do I pass in (access) this row inside here? 
                              For example....  ** */
                        outputValue = myMethod(r.Text, r.Value); 
                        /* ** Can use this records values like this? */

                        //Do a bunch of data massaging...
                        return outputValue; //Return modified string
                    }).ToString()
                }).ToArray();
```

I realize I can create a private method and call that instead, but this is more for informational purposes - how to use an inline function when using linq to shape a return set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i think you mean impossible

Comment: I'm trying to create an inline lambda express that modifies the value before it renders the final output (an array).

Comment: I'm honestly surprised at the downvoting and VTC. This is a poor question, but certainly not the worst and not unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an anonymous in-line transformation, try this:

```
Array result = someList.Select(t => new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = t.Text,
                   Value = t =>
                   {
                       /* some transformation logic */
                   }
               }).ToArray();
```